# Accessing android.os.Debug methods in javascript

Tags: java, javascript, android

I would like to access some of the static methods in the [Debug class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Debug.html); part of the android.os package.

However, when I include calls to these functions javascript gives me a undefined ReferenceError; it cannot find the android package.

How do I set the search path for java packages in javascript?

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this by creating a javaScriptInterface object in your activity and setting that on your webview. Check out the webview method addJavascriptInterface(). The basic idea is that your JSInterface object would have the logic for accessing the Debug class and return the values that you are interested in.

Here is a basic example of this taken directly from the SDK reference doc:

```
class JsObject {
    @JavascriptInterface
    public String toString() { return "injectedObject"; }
}

webView.addJavascriptInterface(new JsObject(), "injectedObject");
webView.loadData("", "text/html", null);
webView.loadUrl("javascript:alert(injectedObject.toString())");
```